# How to Removehandler event?

Tags: vb.net

I had difficulty deleting an event
, I only call contextmenu temporarily (assigning the event and after the event has finished I no longer use it), and so on for each call.

```
sub register()
   Dim f_Cm As Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip = New System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(Me.components)
   AddHandler f_Cm.Closed, Sub() f_Cm_Closed(f_Cm)
end sub

'mycode1
Private Sub f_Cm_Closed(f_Cm As Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip)
 '....mycode
 RemoveHandler f_Cm.Closed, Sub() f_Cm_Closed(f_Cm)
End Sub
'mycode2
Private Sub f_Cm_Closed(f_Cm As Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip)
'....mycode
 Dim e1 As ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs = address of f_Cm_Closed(f_Cm)
 RemoveHandler f_Cm.Closed, e1
End Sub
```

Do I need to delete them in this case? and how to do this?
Thanks you!

Comment: You can't use a lambda expression if RemoveHandler is important.  Use a plain method instead.  Odds that you actually *need* to use RemoveHandler are low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sub() f_Cm_Closed(f_Cm)` is what's called a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions). Lambda expression are basically methods without a name; they're useful shortcuts in some situations. What you are doing in the code `Sub() f_Cm_Closed(f_Cm)` is creating a new, nameless method, which then calls `f_Cm_Closed(f_Cm)`.

This isn't what you want, you want to pass a reference directly to your handler so you can remove it later. For that, you use [`AddressOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addressof-operator).

Before you can do that, the method signatures will have to match. So

```
Private Sub f_Cm_Closed(f_Cm As Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip)
```

will have to become

```
Private Sub f_Cm_Closed(sender As Object, e As ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs)
```

`sender` will always be `f_Cm`, so you can cast like so:

```
Dim f_Cm As Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip = sender
```

---

To pull everything together, your `AddHandler` call now becomes:

```
AddHandler f_Cm.Closed, AddressOf f_Cm_Closed
```

And your method `f_Cm_Closed` becomes:

```
Private Sub f_Cm_Closed(sender As Object, e As ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs)
    Dim f_Cm As Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip = sender
    RemoveHandler f_Cm.Closed, AddressOf f_Cm_Closed
End Sub
```

---

As a final thought, I have no idea why you would want to remove the handler for the `Closed` event after the menu is closed. But this is how you would restructure your code to do it.

Comment: And if you do this, make sure you have `Option Strict On` so that any mismatch in handler signature is flagged as an error.  Otherwise, the "relaxed delegate convention" can lead to code that looks right but doesn't actually unregister the event because VB creates a delegate behind the scenes to forward from the event to your routine.  In my testing, it didn't seem that (through VS 2017) there is an option outside of Option Strict to turn this checking on, even at the warning level.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answer and the clear explanation!